# Replacing text in a file from the content of a hash

Tags: ruby

I have a .TXT populated with the following lines:

`January 1987`

`October 1988`

`May 1975`

and so on. I just want to replace the name of the month by the number format, for example `January` would be replaced by `1`; `February` by `2` and the like. For this aim, I've created a `hash` and a this code so far:

```
dates = {'January' => 1, 'February' => 2, 'March'  => 3, 'April' => 4, 'May' => 5, 'June' => 6, 'July' => 7, 'August' => 8, 'September' => 9, 'October' => 10, 'November' => 11, 'December' => 12} #My beatiful hash!

file_names = ['foo.txt', 'bar.txt'] #The name of the file may change, but extension will always be a .TXT file. 

file_names.each do |file_name|
  text = File.read(file_name)
  new_contents = text.gsub(/"THE KEY OF MY HASH"/, "THE VALUE OF MY HASH") #Here is where I need help


puts new_contents


File.open(file_name, "w") {|file| file.puts new_contents } #Will this overwrite the file, or generate a new one?
end
```

Comment: `text.gsub(Regexp.union(dates.keys), dates)` should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FILE_IN  = 'foo.txt'
FILE_OUT = 'bar.txt'
```

Let's first construct the file.

```
File.write(FILE_IN, "January 1987\nOctober 1988\nMay 1975\n")
  #=> 35
```

It's convenient to use `String#gsub` with a regular expression to perform the substitutions. The following regular expression is what we want.

```
r = Regexp.union(dates.keys)
  #=>  /January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December/
```

Assuming the file it not huge we can *slurp* its contents into a string, use `gsub` to make the replacements then write the modified string to the output file:

```
File.write(FILE_OUT, File.read(FILE_IN).gsub(r, dates))
  #=> 22
```

We can see this worked by examining the contents of the output file.

```
puts File.read(FILE_OUT)
1 1987
10 1988
5 1975
```

The uses the form of [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-gsub) that employs a hash (`dates`) to perform the substitutions. Also see [IO::read](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/IO.html#method-c-read) and [IO::write](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/IO.html#method-c-write). `IO` methods are commonly used with `File` as the receiver. That's OK because `File` is a subclass of `IO` (`File.superclass #=> IO`) and therefore inherits the latter's methods.

See also [Regexp::union](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Regexp.html#method-c-union).

The steps are as follows:

```
s = File.read(FILE_IN)
  #=> "January 1987\nOctober 1988\nMay 1975\n" 
t = s.gsub(r, dates)
  #=> "1 1987\n10 1988\n5 1975\n" 
File.write(FILE_OUT, t
```

If the file is extremely large you will want to perform the substitutions line by line. You can do that as follows.

```
f = open(FILE_OUT, "w")
File.foreach(FILE_IN) { |line| f.puts(line.gsub(r, dates)) }
f.close

puts File.read(FILE_OUT)
1 1987
10 1988
5 1975
```

See [File::open](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/File.html#method-c-open), [IO#puts](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/IO.html#method-i-puts) [IO#close](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/IO.html#method-i-close) and [IO::foreach](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/IO.html#method-c-foreach).

Note that you could construct your hash `dates` as follows:

```
require 'date'

Date::MONTHNAMES.each_with_index.drop(1).to_h
  #=> {"January"=>1, "February"=>2, ... , "December"=>12}
```

You may think this is a lot of trouble when you can just write `dates` out, but it does guard against spelling and other errors which could be troublesome to debug.

Comment: Thank you a lot Cary! So much useful information! Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach: use a regex alternation construct (the pipe `|`) and the word-boundary `\b` to avoid matching e.g. `Maybe`, and pass the hash into `gsub`:

```
dates = {
  'January' => 1, 
  'February' => 2, 
  'March'  => 3, 
  'April' => 4, 
  'May' => 5, 
  'June' => 6, 
  'July' => 7, 
  'August' => 8, 
  'September' => 9, 
  'October' => 10, 
  'November' => 11, 
  'December' => 12
}

file_names = ['foo.txt', 'bar.txt']

file_names.each do |file_name|
  text = File.read(file_name)
  new_content = text.gsub(/\b(#{dates.keys.join "|"})\b/, dates)
  File.write(file_name, new_content) # the file will be overwritten
end
```

However, when working with dates in Ruby, the `date` library offers an array of date names in `Date::MONTHNAMES` you can use to build your hash:

```
require 'date'

file_names = ['foo.txt', 'bar.txt']
months = Hash[Date::MONTHNAMES.drop(1).zip 1..12]
pattern = /\b(#{months.keys.join "|"})\b/

file_names.each do |file_name|
  text = File.read(file_name)
  new_content = text.gsub(pattern, months)
  File.write(file_name, new_content)
end
```